# Forcing a PI scan for teradata table

Tags: teradata

I have a table (say T1) which has a PI defined on column c1, c2 and c3.

In one query, the need is to have filter only on c1, and for a given unknown reason, I cant create a secondary index on the column c1.

I tried writing a query like this -

```
select *
from T1
where C1 = <some Value>
and c2 = c2
and c3 = c3
```

given that conditions for c2 and c3 are tautologies, the result set will not be impacted. However, I am "expecting" to fool Teradata into invoking the PI for this query, which does not happen.

any explanation ?

Comment: Are your statistics up to date on your table?  Also, when you say you are trying to "fool" Teradata, a primary index in Teradata isn't like an index in SQL Server or Oracle. Can you clarify this for me?

Comment: Well, i mean no disrespect when i use the word "fool".  Only point is, the index is a composite one with 3 columns and my filter requires only one.  I also tried to use c2 <> 'junk value' and c2 is not null kind of conditions, none of them invoke the PI, only case when the PI is invoked when I am providing a literal with an equal condition (c2 = <something>), thats what prompted me to use the c2 = c2 anology..

wonder if there is a way to invoke PI in this kind of situation ?

Comment: Can you post the explain plan?

Answer (score 1):

Teradata's PI is hash-based, so all three columns must be referenced with ANDed conditions based on equality.

There's no way to get PI-access when only a single column is known.
But of course you might create a Secondary Index (why did it fail?). If this is a recurring requirement you might better think about changing the PI and/or adding partitioning.

Comment: Well, the secondary index didnt really fail, given that we are a consumer of this database, the owners dont allow us to meddle in the data structures, lets leave it at that.

I appreciate your suggestion of secondary/join indexes/join tables etc.  The idea i put together, is actually reference all the PI columns in AND conditions.. should it really not invoke the PI ?

Comment: It's all three columns with ANDed conditions plus equality, but there's no way to calculate a hash based on that information: hash(<known value>, <unknown value>, <unknown value>)? If you can't change the table's DDL you must live with the Full Table Scan. How big is this table?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hash index or a single table join index with the primary index of column 'C1'. This will allow you to have single or group-AMP access of the index and then a row id access to the base table. The other option, if 'C1' is unique is to create a USI on that column. This will provide you at best a two-AMP operation with a single value or a group-AMP option if you provide multiple values when qualifying.

I am not aware of a method to query the base table as you have it defined and access the primary index without fully qualifying it.